# CSS not rendering on MAMP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, blogs, mamp

I'm working on a Wordpress blog. I'm embedding a stylesheet as follows:

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” href="<?php bloginfo("stylesheet_url"); ?>" type=”text/css” media=”screen” />
```

However, the CSS doesn't render, at all. I've checked that the URL that is being put in the href is correct. The CSS is found. But, it doesn't render, in all browsers. I am utterly stumped, and would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction. I'm using MAMP 1.8.3, and Wordpress 1.2.9.

Comment: Which browsers work and which don't?

Comment: What's the GENERATED link look like? What makes you so sure it's found?

Comment: Use a tool like Firebug to examine the network traffic and see if the CSS file was retrieved and what its contents are.

Comment: The generated link is 'http://localhost/wp-content/themes/[theme name]/style.css'. Typing this address in a browser gets me my stylesheet. Safari, Chrome, and Firefox all don't work.

Comment: Hmm, I looked at Firebug, it doesn't appear to have retrieved the file... but I'm certain the link is correct... there's a 301 Moved Permanently Error, anyone know what that means?

Comment: What happens when you try to access the URL that's generated? Any errors?

Comment: Via typing the generated URL in the browser, I'm able to access it fine, meaning I see my CSS code in the browser. No errors.
My page, on the other hand, doesn't appear to be attempting to access the CSS at all...

Comment: Wow, that was queer. The problem was that somehow, my double quotes got replaced with some other character that looked like double quotes but weren't double quotes. Stupid keyboard. Thanks for all the help, everyone.

Comment: @Debashis are you editing the file in Microsoft Word or something like that? Word processors will typically do this sort of replacement automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I opened the file in Word once, that must have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my keyboard. It created characters that looked like double quotes, but weren't. Upon making them actual double quotes, the CSS worked. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

View Source in your browser and copy the link URL. Then validate it [here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: The CSS is valid, it works fine when embedded with <style type="text/css"></style>. It just won't work when embedded with a <link />. My suspicion is it's something to do with Apache, but I'm not sure.

Comment: is the link in head or body?also the validator will tell you what the content of your link is so you should validate regardless

Comment: It's in the head, and the validator gives me the content of the link correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main css file must be in the root of the template folder and you will have to link any other css files within the main css file

Example

```
@import url('css/reset.css');
@import url('css/typography.css');
```

Hope this was what you were looking for. 
Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

looks like you have double quotes instead of single.

Should be

```
('stylesheet_url');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The PHP is interpreted before the HTML and replaced with a URL. This won't help.